# how to auto register users after valid OpenIdConnect authentication is ASP.NET MVC 5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an app that is written on the top of an old ASP.NET MVC 5 framework using `C#`. I want to enable OpenIdConnect authentication to allow my users to authenticate using a private OpenId server.

I was able to add the OpenId external provider using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) project. Currently, I am using [Code Flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth) to authentication users. After the user is authenticated and redirected back to my app, the user is asked to register a new account in my app. I want to avoid asking the user to manually provide a username for my app. Instead, I want to auto create the account for them using the returned end-user identifiers.

Here is how configured the OpenId authentication provider

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = "openid-server-domain.com",
    RedeemCode = true,
    SaveTokens = true,
    ResponseType = "code",
    ClientId = "***",
    ClientSecret = "***",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:55555/connect/redirect",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/disconnect/sign-out"
});
```

**Question**
How can I avoid asking the user to manually register after they are authenticated? I would like to access the end-user provides by the authentication provider and based on the given values, I would then create the account.